# How to set two array data in one cell content of custom tableview in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

hello I am beginner in iOS I have created custom table view and I have Two array then I want to set both array data together in simultaneously one by one cell content in table view I  show image which i want..

Please refer : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIkaf.png

```
  NSMutableArray *SearchPatientCode;
  NSMutableArray *SearchPatientName;
  UITableView *table_SearchPatient;
  SearchPatientCode=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"PH230130420",@"PH230420321",@"Ph450362120", nil];

  SearchPatientName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Rahul Sharma",@"Amit   kumar",@"anil sharma", nil];

 table_SearchPatient=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130,40,170,250)style:UITableViewStylePlain];
 table_SearchPatient.delegate=self;
 table_SearchPatient.dataSource=self;
 table_SearchPatient.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
 table_SearchPatient.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
 [self.view addSubview:table_SearchPatient];

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if(tableView==table_SearchPatient)
{

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;

    }

    cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ /n %@",[SearchPatientCode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[SearchPatientName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:10.0f];
   // cell.detailTextLabel.text=[SearchPatientName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
 }
```

I am using this But this is not show as I want ...Solve this problem!!

Comment: set Number of line like `cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;`

Comment: ok this is right to connate two array data within string and set text on cell and above this line cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=2               cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=2;
   cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",  [SearchPatientCode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[SearchPatientName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0f];

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should consider an option of storing `NSDictionary` objects in an array or a custom model object `Patient` in an array. If you want to add another details say `BloodType` to patient with current design you may need another array, which is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Add New `UILable` with `numberOfLines = 2`   like bellow...

if you want to unlimited line with your content data then you can do it with set `numberOfLines = 0` and set `lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap`

```
       - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
          {
              static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

              UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

              if(tableView==table_SearchPatient)
              {
                 if (cell == nil)
                 {
                     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;
                 }
                 UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
                 lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ /n %@",[SearchPatientCode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[SearchPatientName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                 lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:10.0f];
                 [lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 2, 250, 35)];// set frame which you want
                 [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];// set any color here
//                 lbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; // set it if you want to height of UILable with its content (Multiple line)
                 lbl.numberOfLines = 2;// Add this line // Set 0 if you want to multiple line.
                 [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
             }
             return cell;
          }
```

Comment: why create lable in to cellForRowIndexpath..?UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]init]; we can also work with cell.textLabel...?

Comment: no with this new `UILable` we can add some features and set different layout. you can not set different frame. also here some functionality its define ny its delegate in UITableViewCell. if you use this then you can change its layout anytime in future..

Answer (score 0):

You can use detail **cell.detailTextLabel.text**.

Or You can create a custom cell and add the labels to the cell like this

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;

}

cell.textLabel.text = @"";
label_name_one = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 90, 20)]autorelease];
[label_name_one setText:[SearchPatientCode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

label_name_two = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(92, 30, 170, 80)]autorelease];
[label_name_two setText:[SearchPatientCode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

set the RectFrame according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change your cell style as **UITableViewCellStyleValue2** then Use this code for multiline text in cell :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:10.0f]];
    }

    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",[SearchPatientCode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[SearchPatientName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
     return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you check out the free [Sensible TableView](http://sensiblecocoa.com) framework. Given the arrays, the framework will automatically display all the values in the table view, and will even generate detail views where applicable. Saves me tons of time.